# How to call method with bind(this) inside a websocket event

Tags: reactjs, bind

I am using React and Websocket to test communication:

```
class Class extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
    this.generateMsg= this.generateMsg.bind(this);
    this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this);
  }

  //generate a random array
  generateMsg(n) {return [...]}

  //websocket sendMsg
  sendMsg(){
    const wsClient = new Websocket(url);
    wsClient.onopen = function(){
      wsClient.send(this.generateMsg(40));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.sendMsg}>{this.state.nameList}</button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(...);
```

always raises err "this.generateMsg is not a function", how to call a method with bind(this) inside a websocket event please?

Comment: who is calling `sendMsg()`? if you have babel [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) enabled, try defining `sendMsg` using arrow function as a class property.

Comment: I am sorry, for making the problem clear, I hide the other parts, I ll modify my question now

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with this code. You need to provide more information.

Comment: right, I think I know where is the wrong part.I ll modify my code again, and now you ll see the problem.But I do not know how to bind(this) with a websocket onopen method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use arrow function like this:

```
    wsClient.onopen = () => {
      wsClient.send(this.generateMsg(40));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you create new WebSocket connection on every sendMsg call? You can open connection on `componentDidMount` and store it.

```
class Class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
    this.generateMsg = this.generateMsg.bind(this);
    this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this);
  }

  // open connection on mount
  componentDidMount() {
     this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
  }

  //generate a random array
  generateMsg(n) {return [...]}

  //websocket sendMsg
  sendMsg() {
    this.socket.send(this.generateMsg(40));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.sendMsg}>{this.state.nameList}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know, I am still try to figure out the life cycle here, because my code send msg to ws server infinitely. I think maybe your suggestion is just what I need to think about.